# Can the ~ほうが~より pattern be used with both an い adjective and a な adjective?

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions

In my grammar reference book the pattern is layed out like this:

- [高い/高かった]　＋ ほうが　＋　**いAdjective** ＋　より...
- [静かな/静かだった]　＋　ほうが　＋　**なAdjective**　＋　より...

This indicates to me that I could say, for example,

男としては、強いほうが弱いよりいいです

(because both 強い and 弱い are いadjectives), but could I use this pattern with both an い and a な adjective?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can:

> 賢い{かしこい}ほうがバカより望ましい{のぞましい}です。
>
> 簡単{かんたん}なほうがそんな紛らわしい{まぎらわしい}よりいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

I believe the example of your own that you've provided sounds not very natural.

Here's an excerpt from a great book I encourage everyone to buy called どんな時どう使う日本語表現文型辞典, published by **[ALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/)**, with many great, easy to understand examples and covering JLPT from 1級 to 4級.

> **【より～のほう】**
>
> ㊀ デパートの品物よりスーパーの品物の方が安い。
>
> ㋥ 私は海より山の方が好きです。
>
> ㊂ 私は日本酒よりビールの方をよく飲みます。
>
> ㊃ この店は、日曜日より月曜日や火曜日の方がお客さんが多いです。
>
> ㊄ 一人で食べるより、みんなと一緒に食べる方が楽しいです。
>
> ㊅ 東京駅に行くとき、バスで行くより電車で行く方が早いです。
>
> １）「N1よりN2の方」の形で二つのもの（N1とN2）を取り上げて比べ、一方（N2の方）が程度が上（下）であると言いたいときに使う。否定の形では言わないのが普通である。
>
> ◆×りんごよりみかんの方が大きくない。
>
> ２）㊄ ㊅ のように、名詞以外につく形もある。

As the second explanation shows us, this structure also appends to forms other than nouns, as in example 5) and 6).

To sum it up for you: yes, you could use with both i- and na-adjectives and even uses verbs if you wanted to.

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all. You quoted six examples from some book, not even a single one containing an adjective and at the end you draw a conclusion that OP can use a construction with both I-adjectives and na-adjectives.